# Django "unable to open database file" after cleaning some stuff from my laptop

Tags: python, django, database

recently I've been cleaning up my laptop and I believe I have deletedsmth related to my database file in django, whenever I try to login/signup there is an error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/login/

unable to open database file

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version:     4.2.2
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    

unable to open database file

Exception Location:     C:\Users\Mechta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 328, in execute
Raised during:  django.contrib.admin.sites.login
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Mechta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
Python Version:     3.11.4
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\Mechta\\Documents\\rasengan',
 'C:\\Users\\Mechta\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Mechta\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Mechta\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Mechta\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311',
 'C:\\Users\\Mechta\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages']
```

I've read some other posts in here and watched some yt videos but nothing really helped so I'm stuck.

Comment: We don't know what database file your Django app needs.  Only you know that.

Comment: Does your user not have write permissions on that file / path? Check your [DATABASES setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases) to find the path / name of the file.